# Html Agility Pack getting value from DIV

Tags: vb.net, parsing, html-agility-pack

Hey all i am trying to get the value from this code:

```
<DIV id=lcm_simlive_countdown>00 Days, 06 Hours, 40 Minutes, 35 Seconds</DIV>
```

I have tried the following to do so:

```
Dim theVidURL As String = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//DIV[@id='lcm_simlive_countdown']").Attributes("value").Value
```

But it tells me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

What could i be doing incorrect?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Text content isn't an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `doc.GetElementById("lcm_simlive_countdown").InnerText`.